# Odoo: Internal Server Error

Tags: server, odoo

I've installed Odoo 9.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I've activated the developer mode to install module from App Store. Every app I try to install that doesn't belong to the 31 apps offered by default without accessing developer mode, I get this error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

It looks like this happens only on the local installation. i tried to install the Barcode app in online trial, and I encoutered no problems.

If anyone may help me, I'll be eternaly grateful.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question?

Comment: Hi Man, now I can't access my virtual machine since I'm typing on another computer. Anyway, i checked the error-log file and nothing was looking like an error like the one I exposed.
I don't know if I'm wrong, but I just activated the developer mode and then I went to "app-> app store" and tried to install another module that gives me this error.

Comment: here is my error-log:


2016-11-27 10:32:58,410 11461 INFO OdooDB2 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2016 10:32:58] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-11-27 10:33:04,281 11461 INFO OdooDB2 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - 


- [27/Nov/2016 10:33:04] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/ir.config_parameter/get_param HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: The last one [10:33:04] is the log linked internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the app on the "App store" provided in Odoo (not the ones that is possible to download in zip and add to addons), are only for the enterprise version.
I tried in a lot of computers and different installation with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Still happenning as of today. I've been able to manually install the module I wanted:

1. Go to the app store web site: https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules
2. Search for and download your module
3. unzip the archive in the `addons` directory of your odoo installation
4. Go in odoo, settings, update modules list
5. you can then look for it in Local Modules. You may need to remove all filters. I've done this in v8.